# Opening multiple files from FTP server using OpenFileDialoge

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, openfiledialog

-Last edit-

I want to pick multiple files from an FTP location with the .NET `OpenFileDialog` Class. Picking multiple files is possible if i set `Multiselect` to true. Once the compiler runs `ShowDialog();` we will get a file browser window. Here we can select files and since `Multiselect` is true i am able to pick multiple files using `SHIFT` & `CTRL` or a combination of these keys. If i type (In this very same file browser window, in the very same in the very same location box) a `FTP` address it shows files on that `FTP` location. I am also able to select multiple files here, but once o press open a popup window tells me i'm only allowed to select a single file from this location.

**Q:** Can i use OpenFileDialogue to pick multiple files from an FTP location? Or are there any other simple alternatives for this? All i need to do is select multiple files from an FTP source and read those into my program.

-edit-
*To make things clear, i am making a program that needs to read in multiple files and process data. I do this with the `.NET` `C#` class `OpenFileDialog`. I have no problems picking multiple files locally when i start my program and use the code that i wrote. But when i want to pick from an FTP source it only allows me to pick a single file.*

*Currently i am simply trying to pick multiple files from `ftp://server.com` with the `OpenFileDialog` class. The methods i am using are posted below. In case someone still has no clue: yes since windows 95 we are able to even use the folder explorer to browse FTP servers and this functionality also comes with the common file browser i am talking about.*

I have a simple file dialogue to pick multiple files. But when I enter a ftp server in the dialogue window I am unable to select multiple files (It asks me to select a single one). Is there a way to select multiple files this way from a FTP server? I need the file dialogue to select files from local disk and FTP server.

If this is not possible i am looking for a good solution to browse and pick files from FTP. My previous attempt at a custom FTP browser worked extremely slow since there are so many files and maps on my server.

-edit-

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Multiselect = true;
ofd.Filter = "Log Files (*.txt;*.log)|*.txt;*.log|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
ofd.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: This seems like an OS/FTP client question more than a programming one...

Comment: Try Filezilla FTP client

Comment: @Bun No it is not, i want to read multiple files into my program. Like i said i know how to do this locally but with the .NET File Dialogue it is not possible to pick multiple from FTP client.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Why would someone program a calculator? We all have fingers don't we?

Comment: I make it more clear, but i thought it is pretty obvious i'm programming something if i post here with the tag C# and .NET.

Comment: No, it is not clear. I don't see any code in your question nor do I have any idea how you expect us to correct a program we can't see.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am using the .Net openFileDialogue, this does not allow me to pick multiple from FTP.Is this normal? Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: I can't see anything to do with FTP in your code, is this just to do with the `OpenFileDialog` and selecting multiple files?  it might be a silly question, but you have held `Ctrl` whilst clicking on many files, haven't you?

Comment: @MennoGouw You just said you used the OS's file dialog, which means your problem is with the OS and not C# specifically. Just because you open Window's file dialog from C# doesn't mean it's a programming question. You need to show some code in order for us to help you.

Comment: @Bun Yes i use the .NET OpenFileDialogue window. I turned multiselect to true but that does not help picking multiple from FTP location. Is there a way to use the .NET OpenFileDialogue class to pick multiple from FTP? Or is there another solution build in solution for picking multiples from FTP? All the code that is needed is already there. I can post my whole program but i do not think that is helping.

Comment: @BanksySan Yes i know how selecting multiple files work. I can do this extremely perfect with the current code i have for local files. If i do exactly the same, but instead of picking from c:\ at ftp : // server . com" i get a message telling me i can only pick a single file.

Comment: @MennoGouw There are eleven comments and no answers, you are going to have to give allot more detailed information to get an answer.  It sounds like that's going to be difficult, but unless you get lucky, it's a necessity.

Comment: @BanksySan I wish i could. I am just using the .NET OpenFileDialogue class to pick multiple files. Locally this works but not if i type a ftp address in the location box of that same OpenFileDialogue window. I am completely baffled why nobody understands this. My problem is as simple as these 2 lines in this comment.